# Script run at shutdown debian

Tags: linux, bash, debian, beagleboneblack

So I am trying to write a basic script that runs a shutdown and copies some logs. To start with I made it simple so that it just prints some text into a file as it runs to help me understand a bit further. The problem is that it appears that the script is never called. Calling it manually runs as expected, but it never runs at shutdown.

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          cpylogs
# Required-Start: 
# Required-Stop:    
# Should-Stop:       
# Default-Start:     0 6
# Default-Stop:      0 6
# Short-Description: 
# Description:       
#                    
#                    
### END INIT INFO

FILE=/shutdown.txt

echo "called" > $FILE

do_stop (){
    echo "in stop function" >> $FILE
}

case "$1" in
  start|status)
    echo "start" >> $FILE
    exit 1
    ;;
  restart|reload|force-reload)
    echo "restart etc" >> $FILE
    exit 1
    ;;
  stop|"")
    do_stop
    echo "stop" >> $FILE
    exit 1
    ;;
  *)
    echo "default" >> $FILE
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

This is saved in `/etc/init.d/` as `cpylogs`. Then I placed the links in `/etc/rc0.d/` and `/etc/rc6.d` by calling `sudo update-rd.d cpylogs defaults`, which places the appropriate `K01cpylogs` in each. I have also tried doing the links manually with no luck their either. I have also tried changing the priority to K99 which still doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Further info, Running Debian 8.4, on a beaglebone

Update: I have changed it slightly `# Default-Start:     2 3 5` so it runs at startup. It runs perfectly fine at startup, but still doesn't run at shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

Probably better posted on [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/)

possible solution here : [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114274/an-init-script-does-not-get-called-on-shutdown)

and here : https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=14582

Comment: Thanks, I'll consider posting there. Neither of those solutions worked for me unfortunately.